# Custom tile server - how to create a layer using Mapnik and mod_tile using POSTGIS db

Tags: postgis, mapnik

I have created a Ubuntu 14.04 tile server.
I loaded an OSM base map into the POSTGIS database and created a slippy-map using OpenLayers 3.9.
Then I loaded data of an overlay into the POSTGIS database and now I am trying to create a layer for it.

To create layers, the only solution with decent documentation seems to be Tilemill. 
But to use Tilemill on my server I have to use "SSH connection forwarding", explained [here](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/ubuntu-service/#ssh-connection-forwarding).
I don't want to create a security leak into my server.

Are there any other options, with decent documentation, with which I can create custom layers for my map?

What I already 'know':

- Create a simple map with Mapnik
- Store shape files into the POSTGIS database
- Use OpenLayers to display the layer

What I need to know:
I have a simple overlay (created with Mapnik):
[image]

This overlay has to be rendered into different tiles and have zoom levels, just like a OSM base map. I want to use this overlay and put it over an area on my OSM-tiled map.

What do I need to be able to create a layer that can be displayed with OpenLayers like:
url: '/overlay/{x}/{y}/{z}'?

Comment: Cross posted at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171789/custom-tile-server-how-to-create-a-layer-using-mapnik-and-mod-tile-using-postg.

Comment: So you can figure that out and comment that, but give no answer to my question? I don't know if you noticed, but both questions have zero answers...